# Is there a good API Doc for Rails Form Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new on ROR and

making some front-end html codes to rails form helper codes.

For example, this is the html code,

```
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
```

If i want to make this to rails form helper code it will be like this,

```
<%=form.text_field :input, :placeholder => 'Username', :autofocus=>true%>
```

The problem is, it is really inconvenient translating from html code to rails code.

I don't know the attributes for the rails code, so i had to google all the attributes one by one(ex> rails form.text_field autofocus required) and this is making me developing really slow.

Is there are good api site like w3schools for checking the whole attributes or option inside here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both links below are from official ruby on rails site

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

if you simply want to make same input field you need to use this syntax

```
<%= text_field_tag :username, :placeholder => "Username", :autofocus => true %>
```

If you use form.text_field in that case rails generate html tag with your object's class for which you have created form_for like:

```
<% form_for Blog.new do |form| %>

<%= form.text_field :username, :placeholder => 'Username', :autofocus=>true %>
<% end %>
```

It will generate like this:

```
<input id="blog_username" name="blog[username]" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above ones, this one is also good for the starters

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-html-forms.htm